# Vapnik-Chervonenkis Dimension

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, subset, geometry, convex

My question has to do with the VC dimension of the class of convex polygons with $m$ vertices. A solution to this problem is given in the following: [Advanced Algorithms](http://compgeom.com/~piyush/papers/vc-dim.pdf).

Call the class of all ellipses in the Cartesian plane centered about the origin $\mathcal{E}_{0,0}$, then all possible ellipses of the form $f(\theta, r) \in \mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ can be described by rotations and translations of elements in this class. Suppose now that the set $\mathcal{C}$ describes the class of all convex polygons on the Cartesian plane. For any arbitrary $e \in \mathcal{E}$, any subset of points $\{ p_1, p_2, ... , p_m\} \in e$ define the set of vertices forming a convex polygon. It should be convincingly realized that for $\rho \in P$ with vertices $V_{\rho} = \{ p_1, p_2, ... , p_m\} \in e,$ $\forall p \in \rho: p \not\in V_{\rho} \implies p \not\in e$, and this statement is true for all $|V_{\rho}|=m \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, there exists a convex polygon containing all finite subsets of $e$. Hence, $VC(P) = \infty$. This same result can (of course) be proven more simply using just the unit circle. This example was introduced merely to reinforce the fact that a convex polygon may shatter any representative from a family of sets that covers the entire Cartesian plane.

Now suppose that $\mathcal{C}_m \subset \mathcal{C}$ describes the set of all convex polygons on the Cartesian plane with strictly $m$ vertices. Again, consider an arbitrary ellipse $e$. Suppose that there are an odd number $2m+1$ of points chosen from the ellipse given by  $V_{\rho}$, then any subset  $V^{(1)}_{\rho}$ of these $2m+1$ points defines a convex polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and further,  $V^{(1)}_{\rho}$ has a complement  $V^{(2)}_{\rho} \in  V_{\rho}$, and as the cardinality of the superset is $2m+1$, the maximum size of the smaller subset is $m$. Hence, a convex polygon with $m$ vertices may shatter a set $V_{\rho}$ with cardinality $2m+1$. In this context, if the size of $V_{\rho}$ is greater than $2m+1$, it will take more than $m$ vertices to shatter the set, as in any other case the maximum size of the lesser subset will be greater than $m$.

Now, let's consider an arbitrary ellipse $e$ given by some $f(\theta, r)$, and define an associated ellipse $e'$ given by $f(\theta, r')$ where $r'=r-\delta_r$ ($\delta_r > 0$). Suppose we label, for any $\theta$, the associated vertex and co-vertex of $e, e'$ which bound all points in the quadrant. Then, for each value $\theta$, the associated (co-)vertices will have the same labelling (say $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$) in the case of both $e$ and $e'$  Now, for any set of points $\{ p_1, p_2, ... , p_m\} \in e$, there is, as before an associated convex polygon $\rho$. Suppose now that we define all points on the edges of an ellipse as belonging to the polygon $\rho$, rather than merely the vertices ($V_{\rho} \neq \rho$). Hence, for any $p \in V_{\rho}$ where $p$ lies between (co-)vertices $v_i, v_i+1$, there exists $p_{a}', p_{b}' \in e'$ between $v_i, v_{i+1}$ (which holds only for cases where original point is not on the (co-)vertex of $e$, $\delta$ sufficiently small, the other case being ignored for now) wherein $p_{a}', p_{b}' \in e'$. Hence, for any $m$ points on $e$, we may define $m'=2m$ points on the associated $e'$. Now define $V_{\rho}' = \{p_1', p_2', \dots p_{2m}', p_{2m+1}', \dots p_{4m}'\}$ where $p_1', ... p_{2m}'$ are points defined by intersections between $e'$ and $\rho$, and $p_{2m+1}', \dots p_{4m}'$ are $2m$ additional points of $e'$. Clearly, any subset of the $V_{\rho}'$ forms a convex polygon on $e'$. What is a lucid way to show that there is no arrangement of the additional $2m$ points wherein one may form an analagous surjection from every subset of $V_{\rho'}$ (of size $\leq 2m$) (call it $i$) to some set $V_{\rho}^{(i)} \in e^{(i)}$ (of size $\leq m$) where $e^{(i)} \in \mathcal{E}$ and $V_{\rho}^{(i)}$ where $V_{\rho}^{(i)}$ forms a convex polygon for some subset $i \subseteq V_{\rho}'$ as being an ellipse containing intersections of lines intersecting all points $p' \in i$. Furthermore, how do I state (simply) that this proof defines an equivalence class of propositions confirming the maximum of the size of the set that $\mathcal{C}$ shatters (No Surjection $\equiv$ VC-Dimension bounded at $2m+1$).

$\dots$

Hence, $VC(\mathcal{C}_m) = 2m+1$.

$\dots$

Elif this analagous surjection may be defined for any subset of $V_{\rho}'$, does the class $\mathcal{C}_m$ defined not shatter the set $V_{\rho}'$ by similar argument ($\implies \operatorname{VC}(\mathcal{C}_m)=4m$)? if so, does the class of polygons mentioned in [1](http://compgeom.com/~piyush/papers/vc-dim.pdf) reference a class exclusively described by the vertices? If the context in which this question is posed is nonsensical/unnecessary, please explain. It seems to me that paragraph 2 explains only a case involving convex polygons defined on the unit circle (or some arbitrary single ellipse). How does one demonstrate that this is a satisfactory solution in general?

Comment: Welcome to our site, Bryan.  You have now made a series of trivial changes, and that begins to look like you're trying to game the system by constantly drawing attention to this post.  We like people to improve their posts (and I thank you for your efforts), but we don't expect perfection!  Please decide what you want your post to look like, make one further edit if you must, and then wait for responses.

Comment: I actually did not know that it bumps it towards the top every time I edit. Apologies and thanks for the response.